# How do I contact users privately?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to know whether it is possible for a regular user such as myself to contact other users privately on this forum.

Comment: Related question: [Is there a possibility for members of the ELL site to propose exchanging email addresses?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4566/9161)

Comment: [On the mother meta, this feature request is at least 9 years old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user), and also thoroughly declined. It and various linked questions should contain a decent explanation of the reasons the site does not support this.

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no private communications between users on this site.

Comment: This answer is rather abrupt. Is there a reason? One could explain that private messaging has never been allowed by TPTB on Stack Exchange and offer some explanations. Yes, I know Nathan posted a highly relevant  comment but comments are ethereal and not answers etc. And the 9-year-old post was posted on Meta SE.

Comment: Comments on Meta are different than the main site since meta is for discussion. This was a pretty straightforward question of whether it was possible, and I couldn’t easily find a straightforward answer in the help center or on this meta so I thought it best to just answer it directly.